# Server VPN affect Users

Tags: vpn, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs-2003

We have two sites, each running there own server.
If I was to set up a VPN on Server A to connect to Server B(about 50miles away), would the clients Internet be directed through the VPN and out through Server B's internet or would they continue to go out as normal? We don't have a proxy set up that I know of.

Servers are 2003 and 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Internet access is based on your local router. As long as that is not changing your Internet traffic will go to your local gateway and out that ISP. If you changed your gateway to be something on server B's network then you would route the traffic over the site to site VPN and exit at Server B.

Can you set up the VPN through your network gear instead of the server? That might make things easier to manage.